# Opening remote files with local Matlab

Tags: matlab, file, local

I can open any sort of files stored in a remote location using local applications except Matlab files (.m). I can open these files using the local gedit or the remote Matlab but no the local Matlab which otherwise opens local .m just OK. I have tried both drag-and-drop from Nautilus (connected to the remote location with via sftp) or "Open with ...".

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: what happens when you try to open with local Matlab?

Comment: Have you tried mounting the remote location to a local directory?

Comment: Something like this: http://xmodulo.com/2013/04/how-to-mount-remote-directory-over-ssh-on-linux.html

Comment: Thanks for your responses so far. Honi, when I try to open with local matlab nothing happens. For example, if I drag-and-drop the icon just moves back to Nautilus. And if I "Open with ..." a new instance of local Matlab is opened without the editor. Raab70, I have just tried what you suggested my and it got stuck when trying to install matlab-support as it can not detect automatically the path to the local matlab installation and it doesn't recognize as such the one I provide. Thanks. I look forward for more ideas.

Comment: I may misunderstand the problem, but what about using the `edit` command with the full path?

Comment: I cannot cd or dir. Edit doesn't work either. The target file is not found.